# Python : Calculate timestamp difference according to conditions

Tags: python-3.x, timestamp

I have a dataset like this :

```
id   timestamp         action                          count
1    1262488099.821    mouse pressed                     ?
2    1262488101.397    mouse pressed                     ?
3    1262488101.460    perform BLUETOOTH_CONTROL_S4      2
4    1262488112.508    perform BLUETOOTH_SOURCE_S4       2
```

Each logged "perform" request is a result of some mouse pressed actions on an interface - and I am interested in how long it took to get to the request.

I am looking at any action in general, that appears in the column "action" and has a "count" > 0. The count given in the table is merely a count of "mouse pressed" actions before the given action was performed.
So I basically need to take the "count" number and look in the past for the amount of "mouse pressed" actions specified by "count". Then take the "mouse pressed" at distance of "count" in the past and calculate the difference in time stamps.
After that, append it to the row of the original action.

So for the example above, I want to obtain :

```
id   timestamp         action                          count       timestamp diff
1    1262488099.821    mouse pressed                     ?            ?
2    1262488101.397    mouse pressed                     ?            ?
3    1262488101.460    perform BLUETOOTH_CONTROL_S4      2            1.639
4    1262488112.508    perform BLUETOOTH_SOURCE_S4       2            12.687
```

Thanks you

Regards,

dkk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigations, I builded this script (I guess that in entry i have a dataset called "data") :

```
import pandas as pd
data_2 = data.sort_values(by='timestamp', ascending=False)
data_2.index = pd.RangeIndex(len(data_2.index))
data_2['timestamp_diff'] = '?'
for i in data_2['action']: 
  index_i = int(data_2[data_2['action']==i].index[0])
  delta = 0
  for j in range(index_i,len(data_2['action'])) : 
    if 'mouse' in data_2['action'][j] and 'pressed' in data_2['action'][j]:
      delta+=1
      if delta ==data_2['count'][index_i]:
        print(data_2['count'][index_i])
        data_2['timestamp_diff'][index_i] = round(data_2['timestamp'][index_i] - data_2['timestamp'][j],3)

    else :
      delta = delta

data = data_2.sort_values(by='timestamp')
data.index = pd.RangeIndex(len(data.index))
data
```

Answer (score 0):

what if on mouse pressed you compare the timestamp for that mouse pressed with the previous timestamp that you registered?

like declare a variable named last_timestamp, and then on a new action, create a new one, compare, write the difference, then change the last_timestamp value to the newest one